# How to cast const char* to static const char XY[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, constants

I'm doing some C# code which is using DLLImport to call a function inside my C++ DLL:

```
[DllImport("my.dll", EntryPoint = "#16", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern void sendstring(string s);
```

I call it like this in C#:

```
sendstring("Test1\\0test2\\0");
```

---

My C++ DLL needs to create a static const char XY[] = "Test1\0test2\0"; from this, since I need that for calling another DLLs function from inside my c++ DLL like this:

```
functiontootherdll(sizeof(s),(void*)s);
```

So my code in C++:

```
extern "C" {
void MyClass::sendstring( const char *s) {  
    functiontootherdll(sizeof(s),(void*)s);
 }
```

---

The problem: It is working, if I define the thing manually inside my C++ DLL like this:

```
static const char Teststring[] = "Test1\0test2\0";
functiontootherdll(sizeof(Teststring),(void*)Teststring);
```

but it is not taking the const char *s when calling this from my C# file (it will report different errors from the called other dll).
I would need to know how I can cast the const char *s to something like static const char s[] or such.

As you realize I have little clue about all this, so any help is very welcome!

Comment: C# strings are UTF-8 (unicode). char is ASCII. Could this be a potential issue?

Comment: you're not using sizeof correctly. `s` is a pointer and `sizeof(s)` yields the size of pointers (4 or 8, depending on the target platform).

Comment: _you're not using sizeof correctly._ How would I use it correctly?

Comment: Even if I try to set manually inside that DLL: `const char *test = "Test1\0test2\0";` and then call `functiontootherdll(2,(void*)test);` it stays the same problem ... it needs a static const char XY[] = ".." some way and I dont know how to make my const char *test to that :/

Comment: Why does it have to be const?

Comment: _Why does it have to be const?_ <--- It does not, `char XY[] = "Test1\0test2\0";` is working as well with `functionttoherdll(sizeof(XY),(void*)XY);`

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I found out a way I think:

I modified my C++ to:

```
extern "C" {
void MyClass::sendstring( const char *s) {
int le = strlen(s);
char p[256];
strcpy(p,s);
char XY[sizeof(p) / sizeof(*p) + 1];
int o=0;
for (int i = 0; i<le;i++) {     
    if (p[i] == ';') {
        XY[i] = '\0';
    } else {
    XY[i] = p[i];
    }
    o++;
}
XY[o] = '\0';
functiontootherdll(sizeof(XY),(void*)XY);
}
```

Afterwards the function call to

```
functiontootherdll(sizeof(XY),(void*)XY);
```

is working fine.

Pls note that I send from my C# code now a string like "Test1;test2;test3;...", trying with the \\0 as separator did not work out. My call with C# is:

```
sendstring("Test1;test2;test3");
```

I don't know if this is a smart solution, but at least it is one :)